# What is `take()` doing here, and why do I need it?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

This code spawns a child process, consuming its stderr and stdout line by line, and logging each appropriately. It compiles and works.

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::process::{Stdio};
use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, BufReader};
use tokio::process::{Command, Child};
use tracing::{info, warn};

macro_rules! relay_pipe_lines {
    ($pipe:expr, $handler:expr) => {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut reader = BufReader::new($pipe).lines();

            loop {
                let line = reader
                    .next_line()
                    .await
                    .unwrap_or_else(|_| Some(String::new()));

                match line {
                    None => break,
                    Some(line) => $handler(line)
                }

            }
        });
    };
}

pub fn start_and_log_command(mut command: Command) -> Result<Child, Box<dyn Error>> {
    command.stdout(Stdio::piped()).stderr(Stdio::piped());

    let mut child = command.spawn()?;

    let child_stdout = child.stdout.take().unwrap(); // remove `take` from here
    let child_stderr = child.stderr.take().unwrap(); // .. or from here and it fails
    let child_pid = child.id().unwrap();

    relay_pipe_lines!(child_stdout, |line|info!("[pid {}:stdout]: {}", child_pid, line));
    relay_pipe_lines!(child_stderr, |line|warn!("[pid {}:stderr]: {}", child_pid, line));

    Ok(child)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();
    info!("Tracing logging initialised.");

    let mut command = Command::new("ls");
    command.arg("-l");
    let mut child = start_and_log_command(command)?;

    // Compose reading waiting concurrently.
    let exit_status = child.wait().await.expect("Cannot reap child process");

    dbg!(exit_status.success());

    Ok(())
}
```

Removing the call to `take()` from the indicated lines fails the build, as "`child.stdout` partially moved due to this method call", which I mostly understand.

I'd like to understand how using `take()` does *not* partially move `child.stdout`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a call to [`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take), which avoids a "partial move" by leaving `None` in place of the moved value. As a result, `child` is left in a valid state and can be returned from the function.

In other words, `child.stdout.take()` is equivalent to `std::mem::replace(&mut child.stdout, None)`, and means "take the current value out of the option (whatever it is), and leave `None` in its place."

Comment: I'd add to this, that it's also caused by the return value of the function.  If `child` didn't outlive the function, the compiler probably would be fine not using `take`, but you need a complete object to return it through `Ok(child)`.  At least that's how I understand it.